# console.log javascript [Function]

Tags: javascript, function, node.js, console

I'm trying to log a function in javascript:

```
console.log(callback)
>>[Function]
```

I want to see what the function is. Can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If it's a user defined function you can use:

```
console.log(callback.toString());
```

Otherwise you'll just get something like `[native code]` since built in functions are not written in JavaScript.

Example:

```
function x(){}

// Prints "function x(){}"
(function(callback){ console.log(callback.toString()); })(x);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if(window.console){ console.log(' write in console ') }` -  be a precaution ?

Comment: No because the question is tagged with node.js which indicates that there will not be a window at all and console.log can always be expected. http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html

Comment: @foiseworth link dead