# Show Attached Middleware Functions in Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, console

I have to admit I'm rather surprised I didn't find any info on this through Google. Perhaps I wasn't looking hard enough.

Basically, I want to find information on the various middleware functions my Express.js app is using, preferably via a `bash`-like console. Logging the `express()` function itself does not log the sub-functions, such as `trace()` or `mkcol()`. These are shown as attributes of the `express` function object, as, for example, `trace: [Function]`, or `emit: [Function: emit]`; their bodies and current contents are not shown. I am able to log the function bodies through e.g. `express().once.toString()`, as said in several answers, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460826/console-log-javascript-function).

This only shows the function body *as it was before I called it* (when I added all the middleware), not what said body is now. It does not show the middleware I had Express `use()`.

How do I show these middleware functions in the console as they are now? For example, if I define:

```
express = require('express');
server = express();

flash = require('connect-flash');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.use(flash());
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

how do I see that Express now uses the `flash` middleware, and, separately, how do I see that Express now uses the middleware that consists of whatever function is exported by the `connect-flash` module? If one or both of these would not work for "whatever the bodyParser.json()/bodyParser.urlencoded() function is", is there another way to log that? As I said, it is not enough to simply `console.log` Express's `use()` function, or, if it is, I was not able to find the trick. There are a million ways in which a middleware function can be defined & `use()`d, so I don't expect any answer to work for all of them, but "as many as possible" would be nice.

Any answer should work for nested middleware, as well, as, for example, the `Router` and `vhost` middlewares can and usually do `use()` other middleware, and are in fact Express apps themselves.

Comment: Wow, that got overblown quickly for a question I hoped would take 2 seconds to ask/answer. If I confused you at all, as I'm sure I will have, please tell me, and I'll have someone give me a v8 then clarify for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing I know of is to run your app with the `DEBUG` environment variable set to `express:router` like this: `DEBUG=express:router node server.js` and watch the output as you use the app. Many of the functions you use as middleware are going to be anonymous since it is common to define them like this: `app.get('/foo', function(req, res) {...});` thus express doesn't even have access to something as basic as a human-readable name for that route handler function.

Comment: This kinda sucks, but your solution will have to be good enough for whatever I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's lacking. I think the concise and freewheeling API and design of express make the kind of introspection-driven documentation you are looking for essentially impossible to create programmatically. But maybe/hopefully I'm wrong and someone else posts a better answer.

Comment: Perhaps, but for right now I'm accepting your answer. Btw I always find it funny in a good way how SO people ask other SO people to vote for/accept other SO people's answers, not theirs.