# How to inspect a function with console.log in karma tests

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

As an example, I am trying to debug this (pseudocode):

```
spyOn(form, 'append').and.callThrough();
baseRecord.$fillForm(form, params, '[namespace]');
console.log(JSON.stringify(form.append));
expect(form.append.argsForCall).toEqual(...);
```

karma gives me:

```
LOG: function () { ... }
```

with no information about the content of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Check Stack Overflow first, like this for example:
[Existing Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460826/console-log-javascript-function)

And to answer your question,

```
console.log(functionName.toString());
```

Comment: U don't see the function?