# javascript getAllResponseHeaders() - how to view '[native code]'?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am doing an AJAX call and attempting to retrieve the response headers.

MY code:

```
 var xmh = new XMLHttpRequest;
 xmh.getAllResponseHeaders
```

I am trying to view the headers in the console and what I am getting back is '[native code]'.  Please could someone advise me on how to view the headers? This question is specific and not a generalised one like the proposed solutions that someone has mentioned as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log javascript \[Function\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460826/console-log-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are inspecting the function itself, whereas you want to first invoke the function, and then inspect it's return value.

Try updating to:

```
xmh.getAllResponseHeaders();
```